# NPM install gyp errors in vscode while gyp seems to be looking for visual studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I am trying to run npm install on a project that I am trying to run locally, however every time I run npm install I run into errors.
Luckily, some posts on here regarding gyp and python allowed me to progress at least a bit. However, I am not having a lot of lucky progressing any further.

Below you can find a few loglines, which to me indicate the issue remaining is that it is trying to find visual studio. However, I am running in

```html
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\User\\project-site\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration 
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.10.4"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\User\\user\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Documents\User\user\node_modules\node-sass     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-12T13_23_17_068Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to install visual studio with developer tools but alass it did not help. So I am stuck once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is being caused by LibSass, a package used to compile scss which is deprecated. You should be able to replace it with [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) which is made by the same people as LibSass.

If you don't want to replace this package I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434812/8678755) that can hopefully help. It seems like you need the Visual C++ Build Tools and Python.

Comment: I don't see libSass being used but rather node-sass:
  "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
   "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",

There's no sass related import in any of the files so perhaps I can just get rid of the dependencies

Comment: [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) is a wrapper of LibSass (Also deprecated). If no scss/sass is used you should be able to safely remove this package.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error (VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer) and resolved it by installing the VS components individually:

Step 1: Download and run the the VS installer: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&passive=false

Step 2: a) Deselect any ticked workloads. b) go to individual components and select Windows 10 SK (10.0.20348.0+) and MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (latest)

Step 3) rerun your node-gyp package installer in the command prompt