# I tried installing the dependencies with npm i, but it doesn't work !! Help me

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

When I try to install the project dependencies with npm I get this error:

[image]

Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM install fails with node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896511/npm-install-fails-with-node-gyp)

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide a sample `package.json`? It seems to be a issue with make. What you can do in the mean time you could try deleting the `package-lock.json` and then do a `npm install`. See if that fixes the issue.

If it threw that error from 1st time running `npm install` that's probably not the issue.

One other thing you could try is to make sure you have the build tools installed on your macOS.

```
xcode-select --install
```

EDIT:

1. Try to delete the library from the cache.

```
rm -rf ~/LibraryCaches/node-gyp
```

2. Delete package-lock.json, /node_modules/ folder, and ~/.node-gyp/ folders.

```
rm package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
```

3. Rerun

```
npm install
```

You can also check [these](https://codeforgeek.com/make-failed-with-exit-code-2/) steps to further debug your issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have package-lock.json  into my folder, I tried with  xcode-select --install but nothing ! it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it's probably some inter-dependency issue, can you update your post to include the `package.json` file? You can strip out any other informations that are not useful I only care about the dependencies.

Comment: Also what's you node version?

Comment: My node version is v14.21.2, and npm is 6.14.17